# how many results are from www.seleniumhq.org are displayed in the first 10 results

Tags: selenium-rc

I am new to Selenium Remote Control (RC). My requirement is that I have to search Selenium from Google and find out how many results from www.seleniumhq.org are displayed in the first 10 results.

I tried:

```
int count = selenium.getXpathCount(
  "xpath=//a[contains(@href,'www.seleniumhq.org')]"
).intValue();
```

But it gives the wrong count, since its counted links below www.seleniumhq.org; e.g download, selenium documentation, etc.

Correct count should be 2 since there is only 2 links which contains www.seleniumhq.org:

1. www.seleniumhq.org
2. www.seleniumhq.org/download/‎

Please suggest the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try belo not tested but something like this should work. I am checking if the attributes are present and your check then provide the count.

```
 int count= selenium.getXpathCount("xpath=//a[@onmousedown and @href and @data-cthref and contains(@href,'www.seleniumhq.org')]").intValue();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.Since solution suggested by you returned 0 hence I modified it to int count= selenium.getXpathCount("xpath=//a[@onmousedown and contains(@href,'http://www.seleniumhq.org/')]").intValue();
Now its returned 4 not as expected.Correct value should be 2.

Comment: Can you please check other attributes in google search result like I added @onmousedown. That is the only way to get result 2. Let me check more, I hope you are still looking for an answer. And another point, as you are new in Stack overflow we dont say thank you or bad answer we just give upvote or downvote :)